# Is there a way to build a twitter stream app with client side only?

Tags: javascript

I want to build a real time app that streams twitter app, but I'm afraid of the bandwidth overhead of my server fetching large number of twits.

Is it possible to have  something like [socket.io](https://github.com/PlatziDev/socket.io-react)  for real time streaming but without involving server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io would require a server. The server is needed so that events can be emitted to all the connected clients.

You could make API calls directly to twitter and just reload the relevant data on page when it's received.

So yes it is possible but you wouldn't need socket.io

Comment: You mean something like fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${items[i]}.json?print=pretty`) changed to what ever twitter uses and have the client refresh the page every 10 seconds?

Comment: Not sure what the endpoint is but I would have a look at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api. You would be better off fetching this server side and passing it to the client. It will prevent any CORS errors and you shouldn't be fetching that much data that you are going to crash the server. It also means you can fetch the data from Twitter once, cache it on the server and serve it to each client that requests it. Rather than calling it multiple times for each client